# Forcing zsh to list options with a single tab when unambiguous

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've been looking through the zsh documentation (http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html) and cannot figure out how to force zsh to list options in this scenario:

Folder contents:

```
folderA/
folderB/
otherFolder/
otherFolder/subFolderA
otherFolder/subFolderB
```

My command:

```
>>> cd o<TAB>
```

What zsh does after I hit tab *once*:

```
>>> cd otherFolder/
```

What I would like zsh to do with one tab (I have to hit tab *twice* for this):

```
>>> cd otherFolder/
subFolderA/    subFolderB/
```

Since otherFolder/ is the only option after my initial tab, I would like zsh to just give me the subfolder options immediately instead of waiting for a second tab.

This means navigating to subFolderA would require these keystrokes:

```
cd o<TAB>cd A<TAB><ENTER>
```

Instead of:

```
cd o<TAB><TAB>cd A<TAB><ENTER>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in your `.zshrc`, it should do what you want.

```
unsetopt MENU_COMPLETE
```

Source: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html